# Use NotifyIcon in .NET compact framework 2

Tags: c#, .net, windows-ce

I need to use NotifyIcon in my windows ce application. But it is not available in compact version of .NET framework 2. So is there any way to overcome this? I have tried `OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` also. But it didn't work.

So is there any direct way to use this functionality in wince 6.0 application?